# What will the network interrupt handler do when NIC recieve data?

Tags: sockets, tcp, cpu, interrupt, interrupt-handling

As far as I know, when a packet arrives at the NIC, the DMAC will copy the packet to the kernel space. When the DMAC completes its work, it notifies the CPU, and then the CPU copies the data to the user space. Doing so will cause the memory to be read once and to be written twice. I wrote a simple program to simulate this process. This is the code:

```
# server.py
import socket
import sys

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "70.202.0.116"
port = 12306
server.bind((host, port))

server.listen(5)

while True:
    conn,addr = server.accept()      
    print(conn,addr)
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            print("client has lost")
            conn.close()
            break

server.close()
```

```
# client.py
import socket
import sys

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = "70.202.0.116"
port = 12306

client.connect((host, port))

data = ''
for i in range(4096):
    data += 'a'


while True:
   client.send(data.encode())

client.close()
```

My machine has two numa nodes. At the first time, I disabled NIC Multi-Queue by `ethtool -L eno1 combined 1`, thus there is only one network interrupt left, and set the affanity by `ehco 22 > /proc/irq/137/smp_affinity_list`. Core 22 is on numa 1. Then I ran server.py. I use pcm-memory to moniter system memory bandwidth, and I got the expected output, the read-write ratio is close to 1:2.

[image: output 1]

But when I changed the affanity to core 0 which is on numa 0, I got totally different result. The read-write ratio is close to 1:1.

[image: output 2]

I want to know what does the interrput handler do during this process, why did I get different result?

Answer (score -1):

increase read latency could be  because device belongs to different numa_node. Check device where server and client is running belongs to which numa node

`# cat /sys/bus/pci/devices/<PCI device>/numa_node`

Comment: Server ran on numa node 1, and client was on another machine. The difference between two  runs was I changed the interrupt affanity.

Comment: No, I was asking that IP address 70.202.0.116 on some interface e.g eth0. Lets first check the numa_node for same

# cat /sys/class/net/eth0/device/numa_node